# An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'SaleController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been following this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection#dependency-scope-and-controller-lifetime

The error I get is in the title:

> Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Basically the Unity code is the same as in the project from microsoft.

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<ITrace, Trace>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IUtility, Utility>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IValidator, Validator>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IDeliveryService, DeliveryService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ISaleService, SaleService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);


        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I have UnityResolver:

```
public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    protected IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }
        this.container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
        return new UnityResolver(child);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }
```

Unity should instantiate the controllers using this. My only concern is the db context. I tried searching for ways to register but I got nothing.

As asked here is my dbcontext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
```

I am using Unity for the first time.

Comment: Can you sharecth the relevant code of DbContext?

Comment: I have updated the question with the db context.

Comment: I have found out that if I register the dependencies scope as TransientLifetimeManager , the programme is entering the controller but returns null reference exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity sometimes custom classes that have a specific constructor also require an additional parameter-less constructor (It may be doing nothing but has to exist) like

```
public UnityResolver(){ }
```

Afaik this is mostly related to (de)serialization. Not sure why it is required in our specific case .. but that is what the error tries to tell you ;)

Comment: Is that in every class?

Comment: No not always ... afaik it's basically somehow related to serialization so the default constructor is required every time the class is (de)serialized in any way. But I'm not sure why it is required in your specific case ... But that is what the error wants to tell you ;)

Comment: I tried putting parameterless parameters on the constructors but to no avail.

Comment: Deadline is approaching and still no info on how to solve this...

Comment: So adding `public UnityResolver(){ }` to your `UnityResolver` class didn't change anything?

Comment: No. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. Still same error.

Comment: Can you add the actual error message to the question? Are you sure it comes from that type and not maybe another one?

Comment: "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DeliveryController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",

Second error:
"Type 'NapLink.Service.Controllers.DeliveryController' does not have a default constructor",

Comment: well in none of your provided code a `DeliveryController` is used .... but it should also have a default constructor `public DeliveryController() { }` then ...

Comment: "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",

Nothing works inside the constructor because nothing is instantiated.

Comment: As said .. leave that constructor empty .. and **never use it in code** .. use the constructor you used so far in code ... Unity just needs the additional constructor for internal stuff

Comment: I followed your instructions. I left both the controller constructor(by adding a second one) and Unity to be empty. I have never used any of the empty constructors in the code.

Comment: And I am still back to square one.